# Expanding A Mask in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, masking

I have a circular, image mask set up in HTML to cover an image.

Here is that code for reference:

```
<div id="group-focus">
    <svg height="800" viewbox="0 0 1000 800">
           <defs>
 <mask id="text-mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
  maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
           <circle cx="600" cy="400" r="400" fill="white">
 </mask>
       </defs>

                <!-- this is the image that I masked -->
                <g mask="url(#text-mask)">
                  <image id="text-focus" width="2560" height="1440" 
                  y="0" x="0" xlink:href="img/Asset13x.png" />
                </g>
            </svg>
     </div>
```

Because I have the mask size set in HTML to the size I want, I am unsure of how to go about expanding the mask to a different size. Can you animate a mask in Javascript? This is for a motion graphic project I am working on currently.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to select the element, with javascript?

Comment: You should use css for that. But if your mask is just a circle, I would recommend using a div with border-radius:100% and overflow: hidden, and add the image inside that div. That will give you much more control.